# Matrix Multiplication - Product of [Row or Column Vector] and Matrix [Lay P94, Strang P59]

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

From P59 of *Intro to Lin Alg, 4th Ed* by Strang & P94-95 of *Linear Algebra and its Apps* by Lay

> For relief, I denote all row vectors with superscripts and column with subscripts.  Define $\mathbf{A} = \left[\begin{matrix} 
> \vec{a^1} \\
> \vdots \\
> \vec{a^i} \\
> \vdots \\
> \vec{a^m}
> \end{matrix}\right]_{m \times n}
> \& \quad 
> \mathbf{B} =
> \left[\vec{b_1} \cdots \vec{b_i} \cdots \vec{b_p}\right]_{n \times p}$ ,
>   where each of the $m$ $\vec{a^i}$s has size $(1 \times n)$ and each of the $p$ $\vec{b_i}$s size $(n \times 1)$. Then:
>
> $\mathbf{AB} = \mathbf{A}\left[\vec{b_1} \cdots \vec{b_i} \cdots \vec{b_p}\right]_{n \times p} = \left[\mathbf{A}\vec{b_1} \cdots \mathbf{A}\vec{b_i} \cdots \mathbf{A}\vec{b_p}\right]_{m \times p}. \tag{Row}$
>
> $\text{ Also, } \qquad \mathbf{AB} = \left[\begin{matrix} 
> \vec{a^1} \\
> \vdots \\
> \vec{a^i} \\
> \vdots \\
> \vec{a^m}
> \end{matrix}\right]\mathbf{B} 
> = \left[\begin{matrix} 
> \vec{a^1}\mathbf{B}  \\
> \vdots \\
> \vec{a^i}\mathbf{B}  \\
> \vdots \\
> \vec{a^m}\mathbf{B} 
> \end{matrix}\right]_{m \times p}. \tag{Coln}$

$1.$ In (Row), how and why can $\mathbf{A}$ left-multiply into the column vector form of $\mathbf{B}$ ?
In (Coln), how and why can $\mathbf{B}$ right-multiply the row vector form of $\mathbf{A}$ ?

$2.$ Would someone please explain how $\mathbf{A}$ can be rewritten as a row vector?

Comment: The expression $\mathbf{A} = \left[\vec{A_1} \cdots \vec{A_i} \cdots \vec{A_n}\right]^{\huge{T}}_{m \times n}$ needs to be edited, as it states that $A$ is the transpose of a row vector.

Comment: @littleO: Thanks; $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\vec{A_n}}$ should be $\vec{A_m}$. I wrote $\mathbf{A}$ with transpose to shuffle out of (gratuitous) elongation and white space. Is this not true: $\mathbf{A} = \left[\vec{A_1} \cdots \vec{A_i} \cdots \vec{A_m}\right]^{\huge{T}}_{m \times n} =  \left[\begin{matrix} 
\vec{A_1} \\
\vdots \\
\vec{A_i} \\
\vdots \\
\vec{A_m}
\end{matrix}\right]_{m \times n} ?$

Comment: Actually $\left[\vec{A_1} \cdots \vec{A_i} \cdots \vec{A_m}\right]^{\huge{T}} =  \left[\begin{matrix} 
\vec{A_1}^T \\
\vdots \\
\vec{A_i}^T \\
\vdots \\
\vec{A_m}^T
\end{matrix}\right]$.  Note that, if each $\vec{A_i}$ is $1 \times n$, then $\left[\vec{A_1} \cdots \vec{A_i} \cdots \vec{A_m}\right]$ is a row vector of size $1 \times mn$.

Comment: I also adverted to http://math.caltech.edu/classes/ma1b-Pr/09Ma1bPracMatrixmult2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

These things are all matrices, so it's standard matrix multiplication. For example,

$$\left[
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 2\\
        3 & 4\\
        \end{matrix}\right]\cdot \left[
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 2\\
3 & 4\\
        \end{matrix}\right] = \left[
        \begin{matrix}
        \left[
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 2\\
        3 & 4\\
        \end{matrix}\right]\cdot\left[
        \begin{matrix}
        1\\
        3\\
        \end{matrix}\right] & \left[
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & 2\\
        3 & 4\\
        \end{matrix}\right]\cdot\left[
        \begin{matrix}
        2\\
        4\\
        \end{matrix}\right]\\
        \end{matrix}\right] = 
\left[
        \begin{matrix}
        \left[
        \begin{matrix}
        7\\
        15\\
        \end{matrix}\right] & \left[
        \begin{matrix}
        10\\
        22\\
        \end{matrix}\right]\\
        \end{matrix}\right]
=\left[
        \begin{matrix}
        7 & 10\\
        15 & 22\\
        \end{matrix}\right].
$$

(Of course, here, there is a slight notational abuse; the last two matrices aren't exactly the same).

Comment: I think there is no abuse of notation, and the last two matrices are exactly the same.  You're using block notation.

Comment: @littleO One is a 1x2 matrix, while the other is a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: That's not how I understand block notation.  If $a_1,a_2$ are column vectors (let's say they're $N \times 1$), then I think $\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 \end{bmatrix}$ is just a concise notation for the $N \times 2$ matrix whose first column is $a_1$ and whose second column is $a_2$.  In any case, I suppose the issue is minor.

Answer (score 1):

The verification is trivial. But to give an intuitive explanation, remember this:

Left multiplication of $B$ by matrix $A$ is equivalent to perform a row transformation on $B$. 
Thus we have to guarantee $B$ contains enough rows to be transformed. Consider matrix is actually multilinear, to arrive at your equation $(Row)$.

With the similar reason, right-multiplication of $B$ by matrix $B$ is equivalent to performing a column transformation on  $A$. Thus we must guarantee $A$ contains enough columns to be transformed. This effects your equation $(Column)$.

---

To see this, take a set of orthonormal basis $e_i,\ldots,e_n$. Remark the following facts.

- $Be_i=\begin{pmatrix}b(1, i)\\\vdots\\b_(n,i)\end{pmatrix}$ selects the $i$th column of matrix $B$
- $e_j^TA=\begin{bmatrix} A(j,1) & \cdots & A(j,n) \\
      \end{bmatrix}$ selects the $j$th row of matrix $A$

Next write $\text{ $i$th column of AB } = (AB)e_i=A(Be_i)=Ab_i$.
This means $i$th column of $AB$ is obtained from left-multiplying $A$ by the $i$th column of $B$.
So all the other columns ($\neq i$) of $B$ and $AB$ are unaffected.
Or we could say the left multiplication (by $\mathbf{A}$) is independent of the other columns of $B$.
 Hence $A$ is actually a row transformation.

Similarly $\text{ $j$th row of AB } = e_j^TAB = (e_j^TA)B = \begin{bmatrix} A(j,1) & \cdots & A(j,n) \\
    \end{bmatrix}B = (\mathbf{A^j})^TB $.

Comment: Thank you very much. +1. I wish I could've upvoted more. Could you please reveal how and why "left multiplication is independent of columns of $B$ and hence $A$ is actually a row transformation"? Also, how can I intuit or naturalise this? At present, I'm enduring/"capitulating" to this via the definition, but I'd like to discern it instinctively.

Comment: @LePressentiment "the ith column of AB is obtained from left multiplicating A to the ith column of B", which is irrelvent to column $j\neq i$. That's what I mean "independent"

Comment: I'd be grateful if you would please answer question $2$ also?

Comment: @LePressentiment If $A$ is written as a row vector, then you cannot multiply $B$ anymore.