# Matrix Multiplying Column Vectors of Another Matrix = Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, intuition

This question is predicated upon [this answer and the comments thereunder](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475926/matrix-multiplication-product-of-row-or-column-vector-and-matrix-strang-p59):

$$\color{green}{
\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}
}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}
\mathop{=}^{\huge{\bigstar}} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{green}{
\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}
}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\end{bmatrix}
& \color{green}{
\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}
}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}2\\4\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}  = \left[
        \begin{matrix}
        \left[
        \begin{matrix}
        7\\
        15\\
        \end{matrix}\right] & \left[
        \begin{matrix}
        10\\
        22\\
        \end{matrix}\right]\\
        \end{matrix}\right]
\mathop{=}^{\huge{\blacklozenge}} \left[
        \begin{matrix}
        7 & 10\\
        15 & 22\\
        \end{matrix}\right].$$

Alex P. wrote: *"there is a slight notational abuse; the last two matrices aren't exactly the same*".
Yet litteO wrote : *"I think there is no abuse of notation, and the last two matrices are exactly the same. You're using block notation."*

$\Large{{1,2.}}$ Are the two equalities signalised by the big star and black lozenge authentic and true?
Alex P. wrote that *"These things are all matrices, so it's standard matrix multiplication."*
Nevertheless, I don't perceive how either qualifies as *"standard matrix multiplication."*
Please elucidate and expound on why or why not? I'm more interested in intuition than proofs.

Answer (score 2):

So my interpretation is that we're simply using "block notation".  If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are $N \times 1$ column vectors, then $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \end{bmatrix}$ denotes an $N \times 2$ matrix.  In other words, $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \end{bmatrix}$ is just a short way of writing
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1^1 & x_2^1 \\
x_1^2 & x_2^2 \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
x_1^N & x_2^N
\end{bmatrix}
(where $x_1 = \begin{bmatrix} x_1^1 & \cdots & x_1^N \end{bmatrix}^T$
and $x_2 = \begin{bmatrix} x_2^1 & \cdots & x_2^N \end{bmatrix}^T$.)

This means the equations in this question are simply true, with no abuse of notation, only a perfectly correct use of block notation.

However, it's possible that my way of looking at this is non-standard, so I'll be curious to hear any other viewpoints.